# CodeIgniter Login Form Wont Redirect To Dashboard

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

The site URL is https://cryocloud.xyz/user/api_login and once I log in, it doesn't go to the dashboard. It goes to my home page. I tried everything and it won't work.

This is my code for the login form. Is it the .htaccess? I also changed the code line 282 in /public_html/system/libraries/Session/Session.php to ini_set('session.id', $params['cookie_name']);

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CryoCLoud  | Login</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/760541018365362268/775421170681249853/Cryocloud-logo-2.png"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <form action="<?= base_url(); ?>user/api_login" method="post" class="login100-form validate-form">
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-26">
                        Welcome
                    </span>
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-48">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-cloud-outline-alt"></i>
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Username"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                        <span class="btn-show-pass">
                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="password">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Sin">
                            <?php if (count($this->session->flashdata()) != 0): ?>
                  <?php foreach($this->session->flashdata() as $message): ?>
                <?= $message['message']; ?>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
              <?= validation_errors('', ''); ?>
              </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <button class="login100-form-btn">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-115" style="color:white;">
                     Dont have an account ?
                        

                        <a class="txt2" style="color:yellow;" href="<?= base_url(); ?>user/api_register">
                            Sign Up
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>
    
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/vendor/countdowntime/countdowntime.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/Login/js/main.js"></script>
<script src='https://www.hCaptcha.com/1/api.js' async defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just the login form doesn't help us helping you. You need to post the controller that is processing that request and everything involved in maintain the user logged in. Also, you should never ever change code in the system folder. You should extend the classes there and use them like that.

Comment: You should need to use `redirect(base_url('dashboard'));` in case the session is true. BTW you should need to post the controller.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code and it works fine :

```
<div class="login">
    <div class="form-w3agile">
      <h3>Login</h3>
      
    <?php
    // Cetak session
    if($this->session->flashdata('sukses')) {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('sukses').'</div>';
    } else if($this->session->flashdata('gagal')) {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">'.$this->session->flashdata('gagal').'</div>';
    } else if($this->session->flashdata('message')) {
      echo $this->session->flashdata('message');
    }
    
    // Cetak error
    echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>');
    ?>
      <form action="<?php echo base_url('login')?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="forg">
      <a href="<?=base_url('register')?>" class="forg-right">Register</a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```